# What is the maximum amount of computation that can be performed in the future lifespan of the universe?

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, quantum-computer, observable-universe

The ultimate question I have been trying to answer is the maximum universal population allowed by physical limits. Making some transhumanist assumptions I am perfectly happy with, I am equating this question with - what is the maximum amount of computation that can be performed? (and making a rough 1 human = $1\cdot10^{18} \text{Hz}$ estimate.)

I thought I'd find it quite easy to find the answer I'm looking for, but was surprised by the relatively limited work I found.

#### Landauer Limit

From physics lessons, I was already aware of the Landauer Limit $E(T) \leq Tk_bln2$. You could then take the reciprocal and multiply it by the total mass-energy of the universe: $C(T)_{max} = \frac{E_{universe}}{Tk_bln2}  =  \frac{1.798\cdot10^{70}J}{T \cdot 9.57\cdot10^{-24}J/K}$.
Therefore total universal computations $C_{max} = 1.88 \cdot 10^{93} \text{ operations per Kelvin}$.

Given a current CMBR temperature of 2.721K, today that would give $C_{max} \approx 5\cdot 10^{93} \text{ operations}$. But obviously, this background temperature will decrease into the future - again I was surprised I couldn't easily find a simple $T(t)$ equation for the CBR temperature, but from a couple of plots I found online got $T(t/ses) \approx 1.38\cdot10^6 t^{-0.56}$.

Plugging $T(t)$ into $C_{max}(T)$ we get $C_{max}(t) \approx 2.6\cdot10^{99} t^{-0.56}$. As a result, going just from the Landauer Limit, to maximise the total amount of computation performed across the lifetime of the universe, we should wait for an infinite amount of time, $t \rightarrow \infty$, and then instantaneously use all $1.8 \cdot 10^70J$ of mass-energy for computation.

So although the Landauer Limit can be used to find the maximum amount of computation in some situations, as far as I can tell, without a domain for $t$, or a maximum rate of computation, it can't be used to calculate the universal maximum.

#### Wikipedia

At this point, I did a google and found the [Limits of computation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Limits_of_computation) Wikipedia page. This told me about 3 physical limits on computation:

1. Bremermann's limit - maximum computational speed of a self-contained system.
2. Margolus-Levitin theorem - maximum computational speed per unit of energy
3. Landauer's limit - already looked at.

Under the section *"Building devices that approach physical limits"*, it also includes a total universal computation possible, using black hole(s).

#### Black hole(s)

In *The Singularity is Near*, Ray Kurzweil cites Seth Lloyd and gives the following numbers for a computer composing of a black hole the mass of the universe:

- $10^{90}$ operations per second
- Lifetime of BH of $2.8\cdot 10^{139}$ seconds
- Total number of operations of $2.8\cdot 10^{229}$ operations

I thought this would be the end of my search. $10^{90}$Hz across $10^{139}$s is (under my assumptions) about $10^{70}$ people living for $10^{132}$ years.

But the paragraph above gives this quote from Lloyd,

> Interestingly, although this hypothetical computation is performed at ultra-high densities and speeds, the total number of bits available to be processed is not far from the number available to current computers operating in more familiar surroundings.

Which seems to imply that a universe sized black hole computer could be really fast and really dense, but wouldn't maximize the total amount of computation across the lifetime of the universe. Given the assumptions I made originally, this is the value that matters, as you could arbitrarily run more or less minds at once, but for a corresponding more or less amount of time (i.e. 2x minds for 0.5x the time). (As far as I can tell, for the numbers given by Kurzweil/Lloyd above, you can't do this as the $10^{132}$ years is a hard limit determined by the time it takes the universe mass black hole to evaporate - presumably the longest possible universe time).

#### Trying to look at Bremermman's limit and Margolus-Levitin theorem

Before, coming to ask my question here, I thought I would check the other two physical limits given in the wiki article.

1. Bremermann's limit

Bremermann's limit is the "maximum rate of computation that can be achieved in a self-contained system in the material universe". It gives a figure of $B = 1.36 \cdot 10^{50}$ bits per second per kg. For a universe mass $m = 2\cdot 10^{53}$kg, you get $C_{max} \approx 10^{103}$ bits per second. But as I said before, without a total time period, for my specific question this isn't too helpful. Plus, this limit uses the mass of computational substrate, I have no idea how to take into account the amount of energy needed.

2. Margolus-Levitin theorem

The Margolus-Levitin theorem gives a "fundamental limit for non-reversible computation of operations per second per joule of energy". $M = 6\cdot 10^{33}$ operations per second per joule.

Using a total mass-energy of the universe $E = 1.8 \cdot 10^{70}J$, we get $C_{max} \approx 10^{104}$ bits per second. (basically the same as Bremermann's limit). But again without a total time period, this isn't super helpful for my particular question. I can say $Pop_{max} \approx 10^{85}$ alive at any one point. But "operations per second per joule" seems to imply that with just 1J of energy you can run an arbitrarily large number of operations in total, just only at a particular speed limit - this seems really weird to me. I really don't understand.

## Actual question

So now my actual question is any thoughts?

- Does anyone have any advice on where to go forward with my question?
- Are the numbers given by Kurzweil/Lloyd just correct and I didn't need to go further?
- For the $\approx 10^{100}Hz$ figure given by Bremermann's limit and Margolus-Levitin theorem, how do I take into account a total time period?
- And how can "bits per second per joule" make sense? Does this say 1J or 1kg can perform an infinite number of total operations with the only limitation being speed? Is nothing "used up"?

For now, making the assumption of $1 \text{human} \approx 10^{18}\text{Hz}$, I have "total universal populations":

1. $\approx 10^{70}$ minds living for $10^{132}$ years. Could you arbitrarily run more minds, for less time? I.e. $10^{100}$ minds for $10^{100}$ years. Or does the use of a black hole make this sort of trading speed for time impossible?
2. $\approx 10^{85}$ minds living indefinitely. What would the total time be?

Where can I go from here?